# Android Ui using Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am currently developing an application which is based on android but am facing some problems on customizing tabs in the action bar. How would I create and import the customizable tab in android?

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136) one and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

See [greendroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) is action bar. It's open source.